# Angular 2 & 4 SharedModule

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I have a problem with angular 2&4 and need help on this subject.

Problem :
We are development some project with angular 2&4 and we use KendoUI plugins.Every component has own module.Every time we import each component kendoUI plugins.

## Project structrue :

```
--app
 -layout
   --componentA
   --componentB
 -login
 -shared
   -- authGuard
   -- shared.module.ts ()
```

## Project has routing with lazy load[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQfKx.png)

Component A and Component B has kendo grid imported like this:

`import { GridModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GU3M3.png)

Question :

Why import 3th party  plugins every component ? Is there a way for one import module , class ... etc and this defined class or module import one times in project ?

Thanks.
Emrah Esen

Comment: You can create a shared module, where you put you 3rd party plugin and export them, then you can import the shared module in every module in your app. Take a look here : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#shared-module

Comment: Thank you for this information.

Comment: Did it answer your question ?